# Multiple in memory instances of same model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say I have a process that fixes the username and email of a User model.

```
def fix_model(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(user_id)
    fix_username(user)
    # lets say for arguments' sake that we can't pass the user to fix_email (call it legacy)
    fix_email(user_id)
    user.save()

def fix_username(user):
    user.username = 'correct_username'

def fix_email(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(user_id)
    user.email = 'correct_email'
    user.save() # <-- necessary because it is a standalone task
```

Of course what will happen is that the user will first be saved inside the fix email call and then the in memory object is saved with the correct username. When we check the database afterwards we don't have the correct email address anymore.

Of course this is a contrived example. There are many easy ways to fix it here, e.g. moving the user.save() up one line or return the instance of user in fix_email etc.
In my real use case i have no direct control over when the models will be saved or the signature of the methods.

My question is the following: Is there a way in Django to have all instances that are retrieved from the database pass through a manager of sorts, that will return pointers to the same in memory objects to all get calls. On save/refresh it will update the in-memory instance so that all existing pointers will also be changed.

I would want something like this:

```
u1 = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
u1.username = 'correct_username'
u2 = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
assert u2.username == 'correct_username'
u2.refresh_from_db()
assert u1.username != 'correct_username'
```

EDIT:
In my particular usecase the equivalent of the fix_email method is an expensive stand-alone task that runs on a schedule (async) but can also be incorporated in the general flow like fix_model() is doing (sync).

Comment: Even if this were available, it wouldn't work across processes, so would not be guaranteed to always work in a production environment.

Comment: That is true. And in the case of multiple different processes you will have raise conditions that can be 'fixed' with database locking. The problem in this particular case is that my equivalent of 'fix_email' can be run synchronously as part of a bigger flow. But also asynchronously as part of a scheduled task.